# Wrong language bibliography title with biblatex and babel

Tags: biblatex, babel

With `babel` in use and `main=english`, nonetheless `biblatex` together with `babel` is erroneously naming the bibliography "Bibliografia". This happens with both the default back-end `biber` (shown here) and with option `backend=bibtex`.

Is this a bug?

(Of course a workaround is to use: `\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]`.)

This does *not* occur when `babel` is not used.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{foo1999,
  title={Title},
  author={Doe, John},
  journal={International Journal of Nonsense},
  year={1999}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[russian,french,ngerman,polish,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

See this book:
\cite{foo1999}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Wrong language for bibliography title]

Comment: I get "References" as the title of the bibliography when I run your example.

Comment: What Don Hosek says: I get the expected (and English) 'References' in the MWE. Compile again or delete the auxiliary files and recompile from scratch.

Comment: @moewe: Are you using the latest `babel`, version 3.49, dated 2020/10/03. That's the version causing the error. To eliminate the error, one must delete `main=` in the options! (In babel.pdf for that version, see the Note at the bottom of page 6, and the discussion preceding it.) This is definitely a change in the way `babel` is interacting with LaTeX and other packages.

Comment: Oh yea, I still have 3.48. I think you are experiencing the bug https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/96, which should hopefully be resolved soon.

Comment: `babel` 3.50 with the fix for this bug was released yesterday (or the day before yesterday) and should be available for updating in both TeX Live and MikTeX now. I voted to close this question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565526/35864 since both questions are about the same issue, but the other question is slightly more general.