# Babel 3.49 breaks things!

Tags: babel

This is really a "beware" posting rather than a question, although I provide the work-around that has appeared elsewhere.

**The new "feature":** Babel Version 3.49, dated 2020/10/03, used with an option `main=[mainlanguage]` breaks things such as the language used for "Figure" with LaTeX generally, "Proof" with `amstheorem`, "References" for `printbibliography` with `biblatex`/`biber` or `bibtex`, and "Index" from `\makeindex` and `\printindex`. Example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{foo1999,
  title={Title},
  author={Doe, John},
  journal={International Journal of Nonsense},
  year={1999}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[russian,french,ngerman,polish,main=english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\index{arithmetic}
$2+2 = 4$.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
$2+2 = 2+(1+1) = (2+1) + 1 = 3 + 1 = 4$.
\end{proof}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\framebox[2in][c]{\rule{0pt}{2in}}
\caption{Look at this!}
\end{figure}

See this book:
\cite{foo1999}

\printbibliography
\nopagebreak
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image: Broken titles using Babel 3.49]

**Cure for the feature:"** Just replace `main=english` from the `babel` option list with `english` (or similarly, whatever the main language is, put it last in the list).

In the docs for Babel 3.49, see the Note at the bottom of page 6, and the discussion preceding it.

**Related:**

[Wrong language bibliography title with biblatex and babel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565388/13492)

https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/96

Comment: probably this https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/96

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, I was in the process of adding that github link but wanted to post the caution as soon as possible, lest others be "burned" the way I was with such an unexpected change.

Comment: Probably better to post the solution in an answer-post, rather than as part of the question.

Comment: I deleted inadvertently a line of code. I've just submitted to CTAN a new version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug in a package that has been fixed.

Comment: @JavierBezos: No, this is *not* a "fixed" bug, so far as I can see The bug &mdash; at least a dramatic, incompatible change in behavior has not been eliminated, at least not with the current babel Version 3.49. The MWE in my OP still gives the spurious non-English names for "Proof", "Figure", "References", and "Index"!

Comment: The current version is 3.50: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel .

Comment: @JavierBezos: This was a problem of lag in the new `babel` appearing to TeXLive Utility in the repository. Finally today it is indeed version 3.50, and the feature/bug has been fixed.

Comment: @murray I'm glad it was solved.